# i get an pygame.error: video system not initialised error everytime i run the program

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

this is the code its a mess right now. i have seen some questions with the same problem but the answer was about not initialising pygame which i did in the beginning of the program. im really confused right now as to why it showing up. can anyone help.is it because i use display.update() everywhere.

```
import math
import random
import pygame
import heapdict

BLACK=(0,0,0)
WHITE=(255,255,255)
RED=(255,0,0)
GREEN=(0,255,0)
BLUE=(0,0,255)
GREY=(122,122,122)

pygame.init()

class app:
    
    def __init__(self,num=80):
        
        
        self.win=pygame.display.set_mode()
        self.win.fill((255,155,0))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Pathfinding Visualizer')
        self.rectdict={}
        self.font=pygame.font.SysFont('Arial',25)
        self.buttons={}
        self.blocked=[]
        self.x=0
        self.y=0
        self.width=10
        self.num=num
        self.restrict=False
        self.loop=True
        self.new=True
        self.start=None
        self.end=None
    
    def drawRect(self):
        
        for i in range(self.num):
            for j in range(self.num):
                a=pygame.draw.rect(self.win,WHITE,(self.x+j*self.width,self.y+i*self.width,self.width,self.width))
                self.rectdict[i,j]=a
        rect1=pygame.draw.rect(self.win,WHITE,(self.width * self.num + 30,20,180,40))
        rect2=pygame.draw.rect(self.win,WHITE,(self.width * self.num + 30,80,180,40))
        rect3=pygame.draw.rect(self.win,WHITE,(self.width * self.num + 30,140,180,40))
        rect4=pygame.draw.rect(self.win,WHITE,(self.width * self.num + 30,200,180,40))
        rect5=pygame.draw.rect(self.win,WHITE,(self.width * self.num + 30,260,180,40))
        self.buttons.update({
        'Generate maze':rect1,
        'Djikstra':rect2,
        'Greedy':rect3,
        'A star':rect4,
        'Clear':rect5
        })
        pygame.display.update()
        
    def drawText(self):
        
        self.win.blit(self.font.render('Generate maze',True,(0,0,0)),(self.width * self.num + 35,22))
        self.win.blit(self.font.render('Djikstra',True,(0,0,0)),(self.width * self.num + 75,82))
        self.win.blit(self.font.render('Greedy',True,(0,0,0)),(self.width * self.num + 75,142))
        self.win.blit(self.font.render('A star',True,(0,0,0)),(self.width * self.num + 80,202))
        self.win.blit(self.font.render('Clear screen',True,(0,0,0)),(self.width * self.num + 50,262))
        
        pygame.display.update()
    
    def flush(self):
        
        self.start=None
        self.end=None
        self.restrict=False
        self.blocked=[]
        self.rectdict={}
        self.drawRect()
        self.drawText()
        
    def run(self):
        
        while self.loop:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                    self.loop=False
                    pygame.quit()
                if self.new:
                    self.drawRect()
                    self.drawText()
                    self.new=False
                if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    self.handle_mouse_motion()
                if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    self.mouse_up()
            pygame.display.update()
            
    def mouse_up(self):
            for button in self.buttons:
                if self.buttons[button].collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    if button=='Generate maze':
                        maze(self.win,self.rectdict,self.start,self.end,self.blocked,self.num)
                        self.restrict=True
                        return
                    if button=='Djikstra':
                        algorithms(self.win,self.rectdict,self.start,self.end,self.blocked).djikstra()
                        return
                    if button=='Greedy':
                        algorithms(self.win,self.rectdict,self.start,self.end,self.blocked).greedy()
                        return
                    if button=='A star':
                        algorithms(self.win,self.rectdict,self.start,self.end,self.blocked).astar()
                        return
                    if button=='Clear':
                        self.flush()
                        return
            
    def handle_mouse_motion(self):
        
        for rect in self.rectdict:
            if self.rectdict[rect].collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                if not self.start:
                    self.start=rect
                    self.draw_rect(rect,BLUE)
                elif not self.end and rect!=self.start:
                    self.end=rect
                    self.draw_rect(rect,RED)
                else:
                    if rect!=self.start and rect!=self.end and not self.restrict:
                        self.blocked.append(rect)
                        self.draw_rect(rect,BLACK)
                        
                        
    def draw_rect(self,rect,color):
        
        rect=self.rectdict[rect]
        pygame.draw.rect(self.win,color,(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height))
                    

class algorithms:
    
    def __init__(self,win,rectdict,start,end,blocked):
        self.queue=heapdict.heapdict()
        self.win=win
        self.blocked=blocked
        self.rectdict=rectdict
        self.start=start
        self.end=end
        self.value=0
        for i in self.rectdict:
            if i not in self.blocked and i!=self.start and i!=self.end:
                rect=rectdict[i]
                pygame.draw.rect(self.win,WHITE,(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height))
        pygame.display.update()
    def djikstra(self):
        if not self.start or not self.end:
            return
        for i in self.rectdict:
            if i==self.start:
                self.queue[i]=0
            elif i not in self.blocked:
                self.queue[i]=float('inf')
        prevnode={}
        s=self.queue.popitem()[0]
        prevnode[s]=None
        while self.queue:
            for i in self.neighbours(self.start):
                if i in self.queue:
                    if 1+self.value<self.queue[i]:
                        self.queue[i]=1+self.value
                        prevnode[i]=self.start
                        rect=self.rectdict[i]
                        pygame.draw.rect(self.win,GREY,(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height))
            pygame.display.update()
            self.start,self.value=self.queue.popitem()
            if self.start==self.end:
                self.showPath(prevnode)
                break
            
    
    def astar(self):
        if not self.start or not self.end:
            return
        for i in self.rectdict:
            if i==self.start:
                self.queue[i]=0+(abs(self.start[0]-self.end[0])+abs(self.start[1]-self.end[1]))
            elif i not in self.blocked:
                self.queue[i]=float('inf')
        prevnode={}
        s=self.queue.popitem()[0]
        prevnode[s]=None
        while self.queue:
            for i in self.neighbours(self.start):
                hcost=abs(i[0]-self.end[0])+abs(i[1]-self.end[1])
                #hcost=max(abs(i[0]-self.end[0]),abs(i[1]-self.end[1]))
                #hcost=math.sqrt((self.end[0]-i[0])**2+(self.end[1]-i[1])**2)
                if i in self.queue:
                    if 1+hcost+self.value<self.queue[i]:
                        self.queue[i]=1+self.value+hcost
                        prevnode[i]=self.start
                        rect=self.rectdict[i]
                        pygame.draw.rect(self.win,GREY,(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height))
            pygame.display.update()
            self.start,self.value=self.queue.popitem()
            self.value=self.value-(abs(self.start[0]-self.end[0])+abs(self.start[1]-self.end[1]))
            #self.value=self.value-max(abs(self.start[0]-self.end[0]),abs(self.start[1]-self.end[1]))
            #self.value=self.value-math.sqrt((self.end[0]-self.start[0])**2+(self.end[1]-self.start[1])**2)
            if self.start==self.end:
                self.showPath(prevnode)
                return
            
    def showPath(self,prevnode,s=None):
        if s:
            a=s
        else:
            a=self.start
        while a:
            rect=self.rectdict[a]
            pygame.draw.rect(self.win,GREEN,(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height))
            pygame.display.update()
            a=prevnode[a]
    
    def greedy(self):
        if not self.start or not self.end:
            return
        prevnode={}
        for i in self.rectdict:
            if i==self.start:
                self.queue[i]=hcost=math.sqrt((self.end[0]-i[0])**2+(self.end[1]-i[1])**2)
            else:
                self.queue[i]=float('inf')
        
        while self.queue:
            s=self.queue.popitem()[0]
            if s==self.end:
                prevnode[self.start]=None
                self.showPath(prevnode,s)
                return
            for i in self.neighbours(s):
                if i in self.queue:
                    #hcost=math.sqrt((self.end[0]-i[0])**2+(self.end[1]-i[1])**2)
                    hcost=abs(i[0]-self.end[0])+abs(i[1]-self.end[1])
                    if i not in self.blocked and hcost<self.queue[i]:
                        rect=self.rectdict[i]
                        pygame.draw.rect(self.win,GREY,(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height))
                        self.queue[i]=hcost
                        prevnode[i]=s
            pygame.display.update()
    
    def neighbours(self,t):
        r,c=t
        return [(r+1,c),(r,c+1),(r,c-1),(r-1,c)]#+[(r+1,c-1),(r-1,c+1),(r+1,c+1),(r-1,c-1)]

class maze:
    def __init__(self,win,rectdict,start,end,blocked,num):
        self.win=win
        self.rectdict=rectdict
        self.start=start
        self.end=end
        self.blocked=blocked
        self.flush()
        self.door={'x':[],'y':[]}
        self.walls={'x':[],'y':[]}
        self.generate(0,num-1,0,num-1)
    
    def flush(self):
        for i in self.rectdict:
            if i==self.start or i==self.end:
                rect=self.rectdict[i]
                pygame.draw.rect(self.win,BLUE,(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height))
            else:
                rect=self.rectdict[i]
                pygame.draw.rect(self.win,WHITE,(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height))
        pygame.display.update()
        self.blocked.clear()
    
    def generate(self,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax):
        if self.start:
            self.door['x'].append(self.start)
            self.door['y'].append(self.start)
        if self.end:
            self.door['x'].append(self.end)
            self.door['y'].append(self.end)
        if xmax-xmin<1 or ymax-ymin<1:
            return
        def vertical():
            li=[x for x in range(ymin,ymax+1)]
            b=False
            for _ in range(len(li)):
                i=random.choice(li)
                for g in range(xmin-1,xmax+2):
                    if (i-1,g) not in self.walls['y'] and (i+1,g) not in self.walls['y'] and (i,xmin-1) not in self.door['y'] and (i,xmax+1) not in self.door['y']:
                        n=i
                        j=random.randint(xmin,xmax)
                        if g==xmax+1:
                            b=True
                            break
                    else:
                        li.remove(i)
                        if not li:
                            return True
                        break
                if b:
                    break
            for i in range(xmin,xmax+1):
                if (n,i)==self.start or (n,i)==self.end:
                    self.door['x'].append((i,n))
                elif i==j:
                    self.door['x'].append((j,n))
                else:
                    self.blocked.append((n,i))
                    rect=self.rectdict[n,i]
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.win,BLACK,(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height))
                self.walls['y'].append((n,i))
            pygame.display.update()
            #pygame.time.delay(50)
            self.generate(xmin,xmax,ymin,n-1)
            self.generate(xmin,xmax,n+1,ymax)
        def horizontal():
            li=[x for x in range(xmin,xmax+1)]
            b=False
            for _ in range(len(li)):
                i=random.choice(li)
                for g in range(ymin-1,ymax+2):
                    if (i-1,g) not in self.walls['x'] and (i+1,g) not in self.walls['x'] and (i,ymin-1) not in self.door['x'] and (i,ymax+1) not in self.door['x']:
                        n=i
                        j=random.randint(ymin,ymax)
                        if g==ymax+1:
                            b=True
                            break
                    else:
                        li.remove(i)
                        if not li:
                            return True
                        break
                if b:
                    break
            for i in range(ymin,ymax+1):
                if (i,n)==self.start or (i,n)==self.end:
                    self.door['y'].append((i,n))
                elif i==j:
                    self.door['y'].append((j,n))
                else:
                    self.blocked.append((i,n))
                    rect=self.rectdict[i,n]
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.win,BLACK,(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height))
                self.walls['x'].append((n,i))
            pygame.display.update()
            #pygame.time.delay(50)
            self.generate(xmin,n-1,ymin,ymax)
            self.generate(n+1,xmax,ymin,ymax)
        if ymax-ymin>xmax-xmin:
            if vertical():
                horizontal()
        elif xmax-xmin>ymax-ymin:
            if horizontal():
                vertical()
        else:
            li=[vertical,horizontal]
            p=random.choice(li)
            if p():
                li.remove(p)
                li[0]()
                    
                    
if __name__=='__main__':
    app().run()
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting and accepting @Rabbid76 answer. This helps SO contributors to see which question still requires attention and it's helpful for people that face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do not `quit` pygame in the application loop, but `quit` after the application loop:

```py
class app:
    # [...]

    def run(self):
        
        while self.loop:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                    self.loop=False
                    # pygame.quit()                 <--- DELETE
                if self.new:
                    self.drawRect()
                    self.drawText()
                    self.new=False
                if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    self.handle_mouse_motion()
                if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    self.mouse_up()
            pygame.display.update()

        pygame.quit()                             # <--- INSERT
```

`pygame.quit()` complete quits pygame and terminates the video system. If you `QUIT` then the loop will still run to its end and any pygame statements following `pygame.quit` will fail.